# How can I include multiple recipients in a gmail email message?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, mailmessage

I've got this working code to send an email using my gmail account:

```
public static void SendEmail(string fullName, string toEmail, string HH, string HHEmailAddr)
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress(FROM_EMAIL, FROM_EMAIL_NAME);
    var toAddress = new MailAddress(toEmail, fullName);
    var toAddressHH = new MailAddress(HHEmailAddr, HH);
    string fromPassword = GMAIL_PASSWORD;

    List<String> htmlBody = new List<string>
    {
        "<html><body>",
        . . .
        "</body></html>"
    };
    var body = string.Join("", htmlBody.ToArray());

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to send the email to two recipients, not one. I can theoretically add another message to the end of that code like so:

```
    . . .
    using (var messageHH = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddressHH)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(messageHH);
    }
}
```

...sending two emails from one code block, but what I really want to do is something like this:

```
List<MailAddress> recipients = new List<MailAddress>();
recipients.Add(toAddress);
recipients.Add(toAddressHH);
. . .
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, recipients)
```

...but there seems to no such overload for MailMessage's constructor. How can I add a second recipient to the sending of an email from gmail? Both as a co-recipient and as a "CC" recipient would be nice to know.

### UPDATE

If I do try the suggested:

```
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    To.Add("dplatypus@att.net", "Duckbilled Platypus")
})
```

...I get:

*Invalid initializer member declarator*

..and:

*The name 'To' does not exist in the current context*

I get the same with the following permutation:

```
To.Add(new MailAddress("dplatypus@att.net", "Duckbilled Platypus"))
```

Comment: Use `message.To.Add()`, `message.CC.Add()`, or `message.Bcc.Add()` respectively to add recipients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [Microsoft's Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to(v=vs.110).aspx), you can see that the MailMessage.To property is a MailAddressCollection.

The [MailAddressCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection(v=vs.110).aspx) has an Add() method that will append values to the collection.

With that information, you can try something like this:

```
messageHH.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient1@domain.com","Recipient1 Name"));
messageHH.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient2@domain.com","Recipient2 Name"));
messageHH.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient3@domain.com","Recipient3 Name"));
//etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the "style" of declaration, but this works:

```
var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = body;
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("dplatypus@att.net", "Duckbilled Platypus"));
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("duckbill@att.net", "Platypus 2"));
smtp.Send(message);
```